# StackEdit: dollar sign in backtick stretches code block to next dollar sign

Tags: markdown, stackedit

I was using StackEdit (http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/) and encountered this issue.

When I entered this:

The variable named `$abc` is related to `$def`, see how the codeblock stretches to the 2nd dollar sign.

It gives me:

[image: stack edit error]

Notice how the "$abc` is related to `$def" portion shows up as a code block. My intention is to have only the "$abc" and "$def" portions show up as code, while the rest of the text should not have any additional formatting.

Does this have anything to do with "$" being a latex equation marker? I tried escaping the "$" using backslashes but then the blackslash symbols show up.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer behind StackEdit. It's a bug obviously. Can you create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Done =) https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/65

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a bug tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in StackEdit 2.0 (just deployed). Thank you for your report.